# D2: switch statement and variables

Tags: d, dmd

In "The D Programming Language" book I see the following:

> Usually the `case` expressions are
>   compile-time constants, but D allows
>   **variables**, too, and guarantees
>   lexical-order evaluation up to the
>   first match.

Code:

```
void main()
{
   string foo = "foo";
   string bar = "bar";

   string mrX;

   switch (mrX)
   {
      case foo:
         writeln(foo);
         break;
      case bar:
         writeln(bar);
         break;
      default:
         writeln("who knows");
   }
}
```

Result:

> Error: case must be a string or an
>   integral constant, not foo

What's wrong?

PS. I use DMD32 D Compiler v2.053

Comment: foo and bar probably needs to be immutable...

Comment: There's quite a few things that TDPL says that DMD doesn't yet implement. Luckily DMD is improving at rapid pace, so hopefully this won't be for too long :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be a bug. It works just fine with variables of type `int`. I've reported the bug for you: http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=6176

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's a bug but it can't use variables. I could get your example to work like this:

```
void main()
{
   immutable string foo = "foo";
   const string bar = "bar";
   string mrX;
   switch (mrX)
   {
      case to!string(foo):
         writeln(foo);
         break;
      case to!string(bar):
         writeln(bar);
         break;
      default:
         writeln("who knows");
   }
}
```